# YOLO : why does changing the confidence threshold change the mAP@0.5?

Tags: deep-learning, object-detection, metric, yolo

I trained a YOLOv7 model for a detection task. I have only one class, which is the object I want to detect. I ran test.py with --conf-thresh to 0.001 (default) and a second time with --conf-thresh to 0.5.
I got the two following PR_curve
[image: PR_curve with conf thresh to 00.1]

[image: PR_curve with conf thresh to 0.5]

and I don't understand what is happening. Isn't mAP@.05 *defined* to be the average precision at 0.5 threshold ? Why does the value change if I change the threshold ?

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, mAP@0.5 is the average precision at an IOU threshold, not confidence threshold. IOU (intersection over union) defines how to determine true/false positive detections, while confidence determines what the actual detection is.